# Number of audio tracks in mp4 container

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, audio-streaming, wowza

Is there any limit on how many audio tracks can be muxed within a mp4 container format? If yes, what is the maximum number of audio tracks I can package in MP4 container? 
does HLS has any maximum number audio track support?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical limit to the number of audio tracks in an MP4 container.

The same is true for HLS.

In both cases though, expect to run into random player incompatibility if you do something strange.  If you're creating more than a few alternate tracks, test thoroughly.